# Transform Dataframe to vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, type-conversion

I am attempting to pull a table from SQLServer and convert it to a vector in R.

I use `sqlQuery()` to return the table, which looks to be returned as a dataframe. I am curious, can I change all the values in this dataframe to be a vector?

I am currently using `as.vector(nameofdataframe)`, which converts it to a list. I find that if I use `as.vector(dataframe$column)`, it returns a vector, but I have many columns and I feel like there should be a much more simple way.

Comment: can you show us `str(nameofdataframe)` and give more description of what you want?  If you want to flatten a homogeneous data frame `dd`, `unlist(dd)` should work ...

Comment: Do I want to pick single columns (= vectors) from the data.frame or do you want to reshape the rectangular data object with all its rows and columns into one vector? How should the elements be moved to the vector row-wise or column-wise?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. If you take the data frame resulting from a sqlQuery() you need to use as.matrix first and then as.vector to the resulting matrix. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: A matrix is a special type of vector in R, so once you've converted the data frame to a matrix, you can iterate through it as if it was a vector, without having to convert it again.